# How can I get the sum of a colum for each dynamically generated table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with dynamically generated tables per date. Each date has a column which displays the amount paid per product. E.g.,

```
<table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <b>Product</b>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <b>Amount</b>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Kroket
                </td>
                <td>
                    € 5.00 <!-- Dynamically generated -->
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td>Total:</td>
            <td class="total"></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

So on this page are a list of tables sorted by date for which I want to display a total amount.

I want this total amount displayed in the td element with class="total". To do this I am trying to use the following JQuery function:

```
function updateTotalOfTotals() {
    $(".table").each(function () {

        var totalSum = 0;
        var $dataRow = $('table tbody tr');

        $dataRow.each(function () {
            // In reality I have some more td elements and the amounts 
            // are in the 4th column.
            $(this).find('td:nth-child(4)').each(function (i) {
                totalSum += parseFloat($(this).text().replace("€", ""));
            });
        });

        var twoPlacedFloatTotalSum = parseFloat(totalSum).toFixed(2);

        $(".total").each(function (i) {
            $(this).html(twoPlacedFloatTotalSum);
        });

    });
}
```

A similar function does work when I have only one table. But here I cannot get it to work since it displays the total of ALL tables in every table. I am no expert in JavaScript/JQuery by any means and would be very grateful if someone can provide me with more insight.

Comment: `var $dataRow = $(this).find('tbody tr');` and `$(this).find('.total').html(twoPlacedFloatTotalSum);`

Comment: `$(".total").each(function (i) {` must be changed to target only one `total` element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function updateTotalOfTotals() {
    $(".table").each(function () {

        var totalSum = 0;
        //target only the trs from current table
        var $dataRow = $(this).find('tbody tr');

        $dataRow.each(function () {
            $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').each(function (i) {
                totalSum += parseFloat($(this).text().replace("€", ""));
            });
        });

        var twoPlacedFloatTotalSum = parseFloat(totalSum).toFixed(2);

        //target only the total from current table
        $(this).find(".total").html(twoPlacedFloatTotalSum);

    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7dN5D/)

Comment: @user2609980: In addition to the working answer (+1), I would probably look at adding the actual numeric value and the currency if required as data attributes to the `td`, i.e: `<td data-amount="5.00" data-currency="Euro" data-currency-symbol="€">€ 5.00<td>` that way you can simplify the code a lot not having to worry about currency symbols. It also means you don't have to update your parsing code when the symbol changes. Also allows you to have more flexibility for currency conversion , etc..

Comment: @FrançoisWahl yes you are right... else the formatting can cause issues in parsing the value

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Aha sounds like a smart move. The value comes from Razor/C# like this:  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => order.UnitPrice) and the model has the property to put out a €. This of course can be changed, and then I do something like <td data-amount="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => order.UnitPrice)"> which works and gives me <td data-amount="€ 5.00">
                        € 5.00
                    </td>. So when I change the model to not display € this can be a very valuable update to have an application that can also be used in non-Euro zones. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @ArunPJohny How can the formatting cause issues otherwise? A € is always displayed now.

Comment: @user2609980 what I meant was you need to be aware about the `€` and to remove it before calling the `parseFloat()`, if you are using `data-*` then you can split the numerical part and the currency separately like `<td data-amount="5.00" data-currency="€">€ 5.00</td>`

Comment: @user2609980: Your model could have a helper to return the display value while the rest is separate. i.e: `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => order.DisplayUnitPrice) <-- should give the sumbol + price`, `<td data-amount="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => order.UnitPrice)"> //<-- should only contain 5.00 now` your helper property could be as simple as this: `public class Order{public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; } public string Currency { get; set; } public string DisplayUnitPrice { get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", Currency, UnitPrice.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); }}}` or similar